# How to change height of activity stream for Facebook Like Box social plugin?

Tags: facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

When using the Like box, the activity stream maxes out when I set the height to 395. I tried to inspect the HTML for the like box and see that the page_stream class has a height attribute but when I tried to override the CSS below, the page_stream div doesn't expand

.fan_box .page_stream {
height: ;
}

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of many Facebook bugs. You cannot set a height. It only works if you are logged in to Facebook.